# Selenium test is not running in jenskins because of ChromeDriver not being instantiated

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, instantiation

My test cases are not running in **Jenkins** in headless mode.

They used to run as intended for several weeks, then all of the sudden they stopped working. I am getting the following error

> "The page object class site.test.LoginPage looks dodgy: Failed to
>   instantiate page
>   (net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not
>   instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver)"

I tried to set directory path to the driver in the serenity.properties file but it didn't help.

Here's how my serenity.properties file looks like:

```
webdriver.driver=chrome
serenity.browser.maximized = true
serenity.project.name = "Test serenity"
serenity.take.screenshots=BEFORE_AND_AFTER_EACH_STEP
chrome.switches=--homepage=about:about;--no-first-run;--disable-save-        
password-bubble;start-maximized;--disable-extensions;--test-type;--ignore-certificate-errors;enable-automation;--no-proxy-server;--no-sandbox;--single-process;--headless;--window-size=1920,1080;
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = /my/download/directory
chrome_preferences.profile_default_content_settings.popups = 0
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled=true
chrome.capabilities.acceptSslCerts = true
chrome.capabilities.handlesAlerts = true
```

Comment: What OS are you using? (Jenkins running on) You have probably updated the driver, and current version is not supported by java package.

Comment: It is running on Linux but I did not install it so I cannot give you more detailed info.

Comment: You should get an updated version of the [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), because you updated chrome browser already and your previous driver is not working anymore.